# A variable in generic class gets wrong type

Tags: swift, generics

Please consider the following classes:

```
// Models:
class A {}
class B: A { }
class C: B { }

// Cache:
class AbstractCache<T> {}

// Services:
class AbstractService<T> {
    let cache = AbstractCache<T>()
}
class ServiceA<T: A>: AbstractService<T> {}
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<B> {}
class ServiceC<T: C>: ServiceB<C> {}
```

Now when I do this:

```
let serviceC = ServiceC()
print(serviceC.cache.dynamicType)
```

I'm expecting to get `AbstractCache<C>.Type`, but I get `AbstractCache<B>.Type` instead. Why this is happening and how do I get the correct type for `cache` variable in `ServiceC` class instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're explicitly typing `ServiceA` with `B`. You should type it with `T` to behave the way you want.

Try the code below, it might work as you're expecting.

```
// Tested @ Playground
class ServiceA<T: A>: AbstractService<T> {}
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {}
class ServiceC<T: C>: ServiceB<T> {}

let serviceC = ServiceC()
print(serviceC.cache.dynamicType)

// prints "AbstractCache<C>\n"
```

Comment: Great  minds think alike! You were only 30 secs or so behind me with the answer, it's tough when they come so close. Take an upvote for being in sync together.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, but there were typos in my question, sorry about this. Please see edited.

Comment: @Andrey Gordeev fixed

Comment: Unfortunately, simply setting `: ServiceA<T>` and `: ServiceB<T>` doesn't work, as this breaks any overriden methods. Xcode starts complain that `Method doesn not override any method from it's superclasses`.

Comment: I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340127/change-type-of-generic-method-in-generic-class

Answer (score 2):

These lines:

```
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<B> {}
class ServiceC<T: C>: ServiceB<C> {}
```

Need to be:

```
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {}
class ServiceC<T: C>: ServiceA<T> {}
```

If you want the type information to pass through properly you need to use the generic type `T`. Then your restrictions will cascade through all the generics.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, but there were typos in my question, sorry about this. Please see edited.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I edited my answer to match your edit to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, simply setting `: ServiceA<T>` and `: ServiceB<T>` doesn't work, as this breaks any overriden methods. Xcode starts complain that `Method doesn not override any method from it's superclasses`.

Comment: If you're having further problems please show the code.

Comment: I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340127/change-type-of-generic-method-in-generic-class