# Change type of generic method in generic class

Tags: swift, generics

Please consider the following classes:

```
// Models:
class A {}
class B: A { }

// Parsers:
class AbstractParser<T> {}
class ParserB<T: B>: AbstractParser<T> {}

// Services:
class AbstractService<T> {
    func parser() -> AbstractParser<T> {
        fatalError("This method must be overridden")
    }
}
class ServiceA<T: A>: AbstractService<T> {
}
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {
    private let _parser = ParserB()

    override func parser() -> ParserB<B> {
        return _parser
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error `Method doesn not override any method from it's superclasses` at overriden `parser` function. I could easily fix this by changing

```
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T>
```

to

```
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<B>
```

but this will break a solution from this question: [A variable in generic class gets wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338485/a-variable-in-generic-class-gets-wrong-type)

Is there any workaround for this?

**EDIT**

Thanks, Kenneth Bruno, your approach works, but it again leads to another error with types.

I add class `C`:

```
class C {
    var item = B()
}
```

and a simple method to `ServiceB`:

```
    func doSomething() {
        var entities = [T]()
        let c = C()
        entities.append(c.item)
    }
```

This causes error: `Cannot invoke 'append' method with an argument list of type '(B)'`. It seems the compiler can't understand that `B` and `T` are the same thing?

Also please note that I can't define `var entities = [B]()`, as I need to pass this array to another function in `AbstractService` method.

Comment: Part of the issue is that you're revealing just a bit of what you're trying to do and when an answer is posted you add more to the question. Can you post an overview of what you are going for so that we can point our answers in that direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as in your other question you need to use the generic type instead of a specific type, then the method signatures will match to override the function.

```
class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {
  private let _parser = ParserB<T>()

  override func parser() -> ParserB<T> {
    return _parser
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm experiencing another error, please see the post edited.

Comment: Andrey, `entities.append(c.item as! T)` will solve your second question.

Comment: Using exclamation mark is very unsafe and I'm trying to avoid this. Any other options?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev `if let item = c.item as? T { entities.append(item) }` is the safe way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From the question edit:

> This causes error: `Cannot invoke 'append' method with an argument list of type '(B)'`. It seems the compiler can't understand that `B` and `T` are the same thing?

---

Just to clarify things. In the edit code example `<T: B>` and `B` are not the same thing. `B` is a regular type, while `<T: B>` is a generic type, which may represent a `B` type or any of it's subtypes.

Merging the question code with the code proposed by @Kenneth results in the following, which leads to a type error

```
class C {
    var item = B()
}

class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {
    private let _parser = ParserB<T>()

    override func parser() -> ParserB<T> {
        return _parser
    }

    func doSomething() {
        var entities = [T]()
        let c = C()
        entities.append(c.item) // Error: Cannot invoke 'append' method with an argument list of type '(B)'
    }
}
```

Now let's say in the future we add a new type `D`, subtype of `B` and instantiate a `ServiceB<D>`. This would cause the function `doSomething()` to try to append an instance of `B` in an array of `D` which is illegal, that's why the compiler raises an error.

With the code proposed in the comments by @Kenneth, the `entities` array would be filled in the `ServiceB<B>` case, but would always be empty in the `ServiceB<D>`.

```
class D: B { }

class ServiceB<T: B>: ServiceA<T> {
    ...
    func doSomething() {
        var entities = [T]()
        let c = C()
        if let item = c.item as? T { entities.append(item) }
    }
}

let service = ServiceB<B>()
service.doSomething() // Creates an array of B and append a single B instance on it

let serviceD = ServiceB<D>()
serviceD.doSomething() // Creates an array of D, c.item of type B can't be cast to D, the array will be empty
```

While my answer doesn't really solves your problem, I think it should put you one step closer to a solution.